# How to run actual robot code in Gazebo Simulation?

Tags: ros, navigation, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on Guardian mobile robot. It has 2 ROS packages, one for real robot and other for Gazebo simulation.
Mapping and navigation code is available in real robot package and not in Gazebo simulation package. Please tell, how can I run mapping and navigation code in Gazebo package. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260068/how-to-run-actual-robot-code-in-gazebo-simulation?/) by [Waleed_Shahzaib](https://answers.ros.org/users/28961/waleed_shahzaib/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2017-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using the packages from [here](https://github.com/inesc-tec-robotics/guardian_ros_pkg) (you didn't say, so I had to guess), then there are launch files available for starting the navigation stack in the `guardian_sim` packages. For example, `guardian_ros_pkg/guardian_sim/guardian_nav/launch/move_base_sim.launch`.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Waleed_Shahzaib](https://answers.ros.org/users/28961/waleed_shahzaib/) on 2017-04-25**:
Thanks for your answer, I am using ROS Indigo and for Indigo version guardian_sim folder downloaded from https://github.com/RobotnikAutomation/guardian_sim does not contain guardian_nav package. The Guardian packages link you shared also supports ROS Hydro.

**Comment by [Waleed_Shahzaib](https://answers.ros.org/users/28961/waleed_shahzaib/) on 2017-05-16**:
@Geoff I have setup ROS hydro in my system to run guardian_nav package, but unfortunately its not working.
Error is:
Waiting on transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error:

Please help.